# T test in R over large data frame

Tags: r, statistics, apply

I'm attempting to run a t-test over a large data frame. The data frame contains CpG sites in the columns and the case/control groups in the rows.

Sample of the data:

```
        Type cg00000029 cg00000108 cg00000109 cg00000165 cg00000236 cg00000289
1  Normal.01    0.32605    0.89785    0.73910    0.30960    0.80654    0.60874
2  Normal.05    0.28981    0.89931    0.72506    0.29963    0.81649    0.62527
3  Normal.11    0.25767    0.90689    0.77163    0.27489    0.83556    0.66264
4  Normal.15    0.26599    0.89893    0.75909    0.30317    0.81778    0.71451
5  Normal.18    0.29924    0.89284    0.75974    0.33740    0.83017    0.69799
6  Normal.20    0.27242    0.90849    0.76260    0.27898    0.84248    0.68689
7  Normal.21    0.22222    0.89940    0.72887    0.25004    0.80569    0.69102
8  Normal.22    0.28861    0.89895    0.80707    0.42462    0.86252    0.61141
9  Normal.24    0.43764    0.89720    0.82701    0.35888    0.78328    0.65301
10 Normal.57    0.26827    0.91092    0.73839    0.30372    0.81349    0.66338
```

There are 10 "normal" types and 62 "case" types (normal = rows 1-10, case = rows 11-62).

I attempted to run the following t-test on the 16384 CpG sites, but it only returned 72 p-values:

```
t.result <- apply(data[1:72,], 2, function (x) t.test(x[1:10],x[11:72],paired=FALSE))

data$p_value <- unlist(lapply(t.result, function(x) x$p.value))

data$fdr <- p.adjust(data$p_value, method = "fdr")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean to say normal = rows 1-10, case = 11-62

Comment: So there will be 10*62=620 `t-tests` right?

Comment: @SandipanDey Yes good catch. Edited for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- matrix(runif(72*16384), nrow=72) # some random data as surrogate for your original data
indices <- expand.grid(1:10, 11:72) # generate all indices of pairs for t-test
t.result <- apply(indices, 1, function (x) t.test(data[x[1],],data[x[2],],paired=FALSE))
p_values <- unlist(lapply(t.result, function(x) x$p.value))
p_fdr <- p.adjust(p_values, method = "fdr")
hist(p_fdr, col='red', xlim=c(0,1), xlab='p-value', main='Histogram of p-values')
hist(p_values, add=TRUE, col=rgb(0, 1, 0, 0.5))
legend('topleft', legend=c('unadjusted', 'fdr-adjusted'), col=c('red', rgb(0, 1, 0, 0.5)), lwd=2)
```

[image]

As expected, almost all of the false positives were eliminated with FDR adjusting of the p-values.